# WPF XAML Custom Listbox Does Not Position Elements Correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I am trying to implement a custom multi-page dialog that takes an arbitrary number of visuals (slides) and displays them.  The desired behavior would be that the selected item would appear at the top-center of the display area in the foreground.  The previous slide would be at the bottom-left with a lower z-index, and the next slide would be at the bottom-right with a lower z-index.  "Previous" and "Next" buttons would set the selected index.  In the set method for the index, I loop through the slides and set an integer value called "SelectionState" based on whether each slide is hidden, selected, just before the selected one, or just after the selected one.  I am trying to position the slides based on this integer using IValueConverters.

For my Listbox.ItemsPanelTemplate, I tried using a Grid.  In the ItemsTemplate, I was setting the Grid.Column and Grid.Row using IValueConverters.  Stepping through code, I can see that the value converters are being called, and that they are returning appropriate values, but all items appear in row 0, column 0 anyway.

After getting frustrated, I tried changing the Grid to a Canvas and setting the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties, and again, I can see that I am getting good values back from the converter, but all items position themselves in the top-left corner anyway. (This code is shown, but commented out)

Since I know the value converters are behaving as expected, does anybody else see what I am doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

```
<Grid x:Name="DialogLayer">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="420" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lbSlides" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFormSet.InterviewSlides}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />-->
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="600" Height="360" Canvas.Top="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToCanvasTopConverter}}" Canvas.Left="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToCanvasLeftConverter}}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToZIndexConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
                    </Border>-->
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="600" Height="360" Grid.Column="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToGridColumnConverter}}" Grid.Row="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToGridRowConverter}}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding SelectionState, Converter={StaticResource SelectionStateToZIndexConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set those properties on the item container (i.e. the ListBoxItem) by setting the `ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding SelectionState, ...}"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding SelectionState, ...}"/>
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding SelectionState, ...}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="600" Height="360">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew I must be missing something simple.